# fn keys for brightness not working on an hp 6735s

Tags: 11.10, hp, brightness

I use ubuntu 11.10 on hp 6735s, fn keys work for sound adjustment, but for brightness %98 of the times not working, I mean till now only maybe three or four times it worked.
always I must set the brightness from boot time (and if I need any adjustment I must reboot and reset)

and this is screenshot for system settings --> screen , it does not contain brightness slider(this change recently happened before there was a slider).
(I couldnt upload it here because I'm new user level 1)

[image]

Comment: @v2r 
- yes only I have problem with brightness from the begining (BTW it had no problem with ubuntu 11.04).
- I use Windows too and in Windows it works fine.
- of-course all other combinations work fine.

Comment: @v2r thanks for your help and time,
is there any program in ubuntu that can manage brightness?

Comment: the funny thing here is that screen was like your screen shot but now it does not contain brightness slider.
it contains::
what to do when battery low and these things.

Comment: @v2r I edited it  take a look at the screenshot.

Comment: thank you its working now :)) but still I don't know why!!
(how to set this question as answered?)

Comment: thanks too much.
_I can delete my comment but not your comment_

Comment: As you might have noticed, i deleted all of my previous comments, and put the most relevant information into one single answer beneath. By clicking on `✔` mark, you accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having a similar problem and I have looked in a few places but try this...

1. Open a terminal (Program - Accessories - Terminal)
2. Type in `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Find the line that says: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"`
4. Edit it so it says: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
5. Save and exit
6. Run the command `sudo update-grub`
7. Reboot and enjoy!

And if that doesn't work, instead of restarting try shutting down completely for 10 seconds and then starting up again. And I also tried the same thing and it worked for a while but then when I removed this piece of the line `acpi_backlight=vendor` and shutdown and turned on my laptop again the brightness buttons worked again.

Answer (score 1):

recently, i had the same problem. Here is the link with the solution that worked on my laptop

http://algodecodigo.blogspot.mx/2012/07/problema-al-cambiar-brillo-en-pantalla.html

best regards :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Questions, to clarify the Problem:

1. Did you have this particular problem with "*fn+brightness*" from the very beginning, since you installed Ubuntu or just recently and do you use a second partition (Windows) in which this problem does not occur?!
2. Also it would be interesting to know, if the other keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>arrow</kbd> key) you use in combination with <kbd>Fn</kbd> works fine all the time.

   ---

**Edit 01**: Eventually it is a good idea to see, if you used this key-combination twice, for a different task, which might be conflicting fn+brightness), also a hardware related issue, like a stuck button, or bad contact can now be excluded.

At this point it is a good idea, to file a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), after we established that it is only this particular key-combination in Ubuntu, and in your other OS there is no problem at all!

Also take a look at **System Settings** -> **Screen**, where you can change/adjust the brightness manually. System Settings comes with the installed OS, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRUX5.png).

**Edit 02**: You also could install `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`, which allows you, to boot into *Ubuntu Unity*, as you do right now, but also *Unity 2d*, *Gnome-Shell*, *Gnome-Shell-Classic* etc.., to see if the problem is solved there, or at least if the system settings are working properly. (Referring to your other comment, that "*System Settings* -> *Screen*" is missing the brightness-slider).

*I am glad, that it worked out for you in the end, even if it is not clear to both of us why! I also deleted all my other comments beneath your question, as we agreed on it and put them in this answer!*

Comment: :( :( :( after restart it returned to the same old state

Comment: If this question is still of interest, please take a look here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/231/brightness-control/